# TinyMCE API for joomla

Tags: joomla3.0

As TinyMCE has started API integration, how do i enter the API in the joomla plugin.
I have signed up for Free TinyMCE API, and added the domain for the usage.
The TinyMCE version is 4.5.12

Added the domain in the TinyMCE panel

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.